# Is it possible that I moved my home partion accidently?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, home-directory

I've found  that my /home folder now live on a different partition.
These are my outputs of **lsblk**

```
~$ sudo lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0   7,4G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  46,6G  0 part /
├─sda6   8:6    0 651,9G  0 part /home
├─sda7   8:7    0  46,8G  0 part /media/ira/0056680e-7d54-40a4-9691-98d4d3e0796e
└─sda8   8:8    0  93,1G  0 part /media/ira/7660E6D360E6995F
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

and **blkid**

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="M-PM-^WM-PM-0M-QM-^@M-PM-5M-PM-7M-PM-5M-QM-^@M-PM-2M-PM-8M-QM-^@M-PM->M-PM-2M-PM-0M-PM-=M-PM-> M-QM-^AM-PM-8M-QM-^AM-QM-^BM-PM-5M-PM-<M-PM->M-PM-9" UUID="8A6EDE946EDE7901" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="427f200b-01"
/dev/sda3: UUID="a67e00ab-4ba5-4c52-b4a9-b4bf2d729fdf" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="427f200b-03"
/dev/sda5: UUID="3c111b56-2a09-434a-85b7-10f311baa17c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="427f200b-05"
/dev/sda6: UUID="db25af72-2c7b-4d03-b2dd-2c7b5b7132eb" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="427f200b-06"
/dev/sda7: UUID="0056680e-7d54-40a4-9691-98d4d3e0796e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="427f200b-07"
/dev/sda8: UUID="7660E6D360E6995F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="427f200b-08"
```

The problem is that I don't know why my /home is on the sda6 now because it was windows's "disk D", just a storage for mostly media files I used to have access from my two systems (I have dual-boot).

I discovered it once in Dolphin trying to open the disk and instead of many folders I see this [(link to the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7K2h.png). When I try to enter the lost&found folder I just get a red error message "could not enter folder lost&found".

My home folder as I remember (not sure) was on the sda7, and when I try to get there from Dolphin I see also lost&found folder and the same error message.

I am interested in is it still possible to have an access to the files that where on the sda6?

Comment: You couldn't have move it accidentally.  Looks like you installed it that way and wiped out your Windows data.

Comment: Thank you. I see. But I am sure I didn't install it that way.  My Windows is on sda8. And I am very surprised now that sda6 has ext4 not ntfs file system. How to get more information about the error of "could not enter folder"?